# Running EF Core Migrations From Multiple Different Nuget Packages?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am creating a project that is heavily built around plugins. Each plugin will eventually be a Nuget package, but currently they are referenced projects.

In each plugin, I want the user to be able to create their own entities and migrations if the plugin needs it. I already have/find the assemblies on startup for each plugin, I just need a way to run the migrations.

I've seen there is the option to pass in the name of another assembly for the migrations like so

```
services
    .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
            x => x.MigrationsAssembly("NameOfAssemblyContainingMigrations")));
```

However, this won't work, as the main project has migrations as well and I'm looking to allow multiple plugins to add migrations, not just one.

Surely this must be something that has been asked before?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reconsider running migrations for them.

Most environments, especially enterprises, don't want the migrations ran automatically, they want them ran on deployments, so your application doesn't need to know about the migration specifically.

What we did to solve something like this for our 'Service Libraries' we have is a multi part answer.  We needed a way to have a self-contained DbContext (so no extending like you're doing).  We solved it by doing this:

1. In each nuget package, have the 'Data' project with the db context have the migrations in them.
2. Each package gets referenced in the consuming applications' data project.
3. Use the project that adds the dbcontext to the service collection and run #4
4. The build runs off a json file, an array of 'ContextNames' that it needs to run the command `dotnet ef script -Idempotent -Context {insertContextname}`
5. Take that script output and combine it into a single script and then put it in the artifacts to run later.

**To answer your specific question though** or if you are dead set on running the migrations for them, I'd still leave the migration creation itself to the consuming application.  You don't need to specify the migrations assembly when using generics.

`services.AddDbContext<TDbContext>(options=> options.UseSqlServer(...));`

You are likely going to have to use Generics.  Each of your projects should require an exposed method that tells you what the dbcontext type is.
Your projects are going to have to call this for the consumer.

i.e. `services.AddMyProject<MyDbContext>()` and during your `app.UseMyproject<MyDbContext>()` method you'd just create a new scope (below is the method using the Generic Type):

```
using (var scope = appBuilder.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
{
    var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<TDbContext>();
    db.Database.Migrate();
}
```

In these service projects we have, we created extension methods on both the `IServiceCollection` and `IApplicationBuilder`.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddXYZService<TDbContext>(this IServiceCollection services, XYZServiceConfiguration<TDbContext> configuration)
where TDbContext : XYZServiceDbContext
{ ...
 //your logic here
 services.AddDbContext<TDbContext>(options=> options.UseSqlServer(...));
}
```

and the app builder

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseXYZService<TDbContext>(this IApplicationBuilder appBuilder) 
where TDbContext : XYZDbContext
{
    //your logic if needed, plus the migration using the migrations they made.  If you end up doing the script route, you don't need this at all.
    using (var scope = appBuilder.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
    {
        var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<TDbContext>();
        db.Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add `services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), x => x.MigrationsAssembly("NameOfAssemblyMainProject")));`  in each nuget package and then in main project ,in package manager console
write DbContext command
(this command show all dbcontext of your project)
now you can  `Add-migration nameOfMigration -context nameOfcontext` seprately add your migrations